# When you want to use event.target.value on an number (answered)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tableau-api

I'm fairly new to coding, and I was attempting to use event.target.value to change the value in a slider filter I had created through the Tableau API. After a lot of digging, I discovered that event.target.value is only for strings. I also discovered that the value I was trying to access, although it was a number, was being saved as a string (e.g. "32" instead of 32). In addition, because the slider had a number of "value" properties, I had to make sure I was accessing the correct one. I'll submit my answer to how I was able to finally make the slider work as a filter below, in case it is useful to anyone else.

Comment: Hi Rachel, answering your own question is fine (and encouraged) but please add an actual answer below the question. This way you can accept your answer to indicate to others that the question was answered satisfactorily. The text in the question should just be the statement of the problem and not contain the answer.

Comment: I've just realised that you need 15 rep to self answer, which you don't currently have. Please consider adding your own answer once you do.

Comment: Thanks, @DeanOC! Sorry for the confusion, I've resubmitted as a question and will submit my answer as soon as I am able.